# Matching letter grades within a body of text

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex expression for matching letter grades embedded within a string however, I am having some difficulty with certain characters. These characters are commas, backslashes, forward slashes, or apostrophes at word boundaries.

These strings may consist of either just a letter grade, or a mixture of a letter grade and notes left by an instructor. The valid range for these grades is anything from an A+ to D-, with an F reserved for failures. For a particular letter such as C the valid grades are: C+, C, or C-. Grades will never appear embedded within another word. Examples of some of these strings are as follows:

```
string1: "A+"
string2: "B. Submitted with deferral"
string3: "F. Could not read M/C answer sheet."
string4: "C+"
string5: "Received a B- with late submission penalty."
```

The expression that I have tried thus far is as follows:

```
(\b[A-D]\b[+-]?)|\bF\b)
```

For string1 and string2, this will produce the following matches

> "**A+**"
>
> "**B**. Submitted with deferral"

For string3 this expression should match

> **F**. Could not read M/C answer sheet.

But instead matches

> **F**. Could not read M/**C** answer sheet.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

---

Edit:

For clarity a substring is a letter grade if and only if:

1. It is if the form A+, A, A-, B+, B, B-, ..., D+, D, D-, with F (without a sign) reserved for a failing grade
2. It is not embedded in a word, for example `FOA+O` would not match `A+`. Likewise substrings such as `AC` or `FB` should produce no matches
3. Letters separated by characters such as \ / ?' should not be matched, for example `A/C, B+'C, F\D` should not produce matches, whereas `A, C` or `A,C` should match both letters.
4. Letter separated by periods such as `B.A.` should not result in matches. Whereas an letter occurring at the end of a sentence such as `A.` may be considered a match.

Consider the following example strings

> string1: "A-- A-C, A\D, F/A, D'C, A,C, B+D, C-C, AB, XA, B.A. C C,
>   Cat, F, C+, B-."
>
> string2: " A "
>
> string3: "B+."
>
> string4: "X"
>
> string5: "F"

in these strings the only valid matches should be

> string1: "**A-**- A-C, A\D, F/A, D'C, **A,C**, B+D, C-C, AB, XA, B.A. **C
>   C**, Cat, **F**, **C+**, **B-**."
>
> string2: " **A** "
>
> string3: "**B+**."
>
> string5: "**F**"

Comment: Not necessarily. The letter grade could appear anywhere in the string. Grades with minus signs such as D- are valid.

Comment: I added some extra information to my post regarding my constraints. Hopefully this provides additional clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which regex engine you're using but the following regex works for all of the test cases you presented:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/czlCar/3)

```
(?<=^|[\s,])(?:[A-D][-+]?|F)(?=[-+.]\B|[\s,]|$)
```

- `(?<=^|[\s,])` Lookbehind ensuring what precedes is either of the following options:

  - `^` Asserts position at the start of the line.
  - `[\s,]` Match any whitespace character or the comma character.
- `(?:[A-D][-+]?|F)` Match either of the following options:

  - `[A-D][-+]?` Match the following:

    - `[A-D]` Match any character in the range from `A` to `D` in the ASCII table (`ABCD`).
    - `[-+]?` Optionally match any character in the set (`-` or `+`)
  - `F` Match this literally.
- `(?=[-+.]\B|[\s,]|$)` Lookahead ensuring what proceeds is either of the following options:

  - `[-+.]\B` Matches any character in the set (`-+.`), followed by an assertion for anything that doesn't match a word boundary (ensures what follows is not a letter).
  - `[\s,]` Matches any whitespace character or the comma character.
  - `$` Asserts position at the end of the line.

#### Alternatives

Fixed-width lookbehind - see in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/czlCar/4)

```
(?:^|(?<=[\s,]))(?:[A-D][-+]?|F)(?=[-+.]\B|[\s,]|$)
```

Without lookbehind (uses capture group instead) - see in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/czlCar/5)

```
(?:^|[\s,])([A-D][-+]?|F)(?=[-+.]\B|[\s,]|$)
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I was looking for however, others who use your answer as reference may require a solution for engines which only support fixed-width look-ahead and look-behind. How would one modify this solution for such engines? What I have tried is `(^|(?<=[\s,]))(?:[A-D][-+]?|F)(?=[-+.]\B|[\s,]|$)`, which seems to satisfy the same test cases, but I am uncertain as to whether or not this is satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Your original expression is just fine, yet this expression has a start anchor, that might be helping us here:

```
(?<=^|\s)\b[A-DF]\b[+-]?
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/I8pP9V/1/)

Or with capturing group:

```
(?<=^|\s)(\b[A-DF]\b[+-]?)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/f4qKgL/1/)

Or without lookarounds, these might work:

```
(?:^|\s)(\b[A-DF]\b[+-]?)
(^|\s)(\b[A-DF]\b[+-]?)
^(\b[A-DF]\b[+-]?)|\s(\b[A-DF]\b[+-]?)
```

Comment: The demo's for your expressions seem to produce pattern errors. Is there any way to implement these without variable length lookbehind?

Answer (score 0):

The "C" in "M/C" is matched because `\b` considers the "/" a valid word boundary.

`(?<=^|\s)[A-F][+-]{0,1}(?=\W)`

This regular expression will match letter grades that are either at the beginning of the line (`^`), or are preceded with whitespace (`\s`). The positive lookbehind (`?<=`) ensures that the leading whitespace is not considered part of the match.

After the letter grade, we have `(?=\W)`, which will require one non-word character, using positive lookahead to exclude the boundary character from the match.

Comment: How might one achieve this without the use of variable length lookbehind?

Comment: I did not realize the lookbehind for `^|\s` was considered variable length. The `^` could be pulled out of the first group, because its inclusion in the match should not have any effect. Does your regex parser accept this version? `(^|(?<=\s))[A-F][+-]{0,1}(?=\W)` If it is the `\s` that is considered "variable-length," and you are not concerned with other types of whitespace, then it could potentially be replaced with a literal space.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work quite as I intended. It did not produce the necessary output for `A-- A-C, A\D, F/A, D'C, A,C, B+D, C-C, AB, XA, B.A. C C, Cat, F, C+, B-.`

Comment: I've adjusted the regular expression for the test you mentioned:
https://regex101.com/r/HDT7b6/1
Are there any portions of that example that are unmatched which you would expect to be matched?

Comment: I updated my original post to bold where the matches should be to provide better clarity.